# Ajax control toolkit editor is not showing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i am new in asp.net and i am working on the thing where i had to add HTML Editor Extender (Ajax Toolkit). but it does not appear correctly.
Click [here] (http://s24.postimg.org/56f3vdv0l/error.png)!
I used this code...-->

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>  
<div>    
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" width="600px" Height="200px"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" /><br/><br/>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
        Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching, I found my solution to the same problem... use this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

instead of:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Good luck!

This would allow use of the Editor control, rather than extending the Textbox (which I actually like that method as well).

Answer (score 0):

hi please check the [htmlEditorExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/htmleditorextender/htmleditorextender.aspx) sample from ajax control site.

you need to assign it to a textbox so that it will be extended to a Realtime HTML Editor.
you need to assign toolbar properties to the html extender control.
hope this helps